# no module named flaskext.uploads

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads, flask-reuploaded

I'm trying to use flask-uploads for image upload feature in my flask app.

I used `pip install Flask-Uploads` to install and `pip install Flask-Uploads    --upgrade` to upgrade the flask-uploads module.
But when I import it, it gives me an error, here's my import code:

```
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
```

Error:

```
File "project.py", line 3, in <module>
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
ImportError: No module named flaskext.uploads
```

I tried using an older version by doing `pip install Flask-Uploads==0.1.3`
even that doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Suggested is the OP further drills down in changes of flask vs. flask-upload that introduced the incompatibility noted at the end of this troubleshooting aid / documentation. Maybe the maintainers of the packages even can provide answers, if the OP kindly asks them? When futher details are provided I offer to update this to a solution, but for now they seem to miss ...

**Answer [on hold] **

I think you missed a dot. Try:

```
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
```

instead of:

```
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
```

If the module is still not found, than check sys.path and check, if the installed module is in one of the visited places. Like so:

```
>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/some/python', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Empty is current working directory, rest are folder paths and if you know where the install stored the module `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_uploads.py`we know it finds it.

Then if you encounter:

```
>>> import flask_uploads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask import current_app, Module, send_from_directory, abort, url_for
ImportError: cannot import name Module
```

it tells you, that in `flask_uploads.py`of the install package, you cannot import `Module`from `flask`.

So:

```
>>> import flask
>>> dir(flask)
['Blueprint', 'Config', 'Flask', 'Markup', 'Request', 'Response', 'Session', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_app_ctx_stack', '_compat', '_request_ctx_stack', 'abort', 'after_this_request', 'app', 'appcontext_popped', 'appcontext_pushed', 'appcontext_tearing_down', 'before_render_template', 'blueprints', 'cli', 'config', 'copy_current_request_context', 'ctx', 'current_app', 'escape', 'flash', 'g', 'get_flashed_messages', 'get_template_attribute', 'globals', 'got_request_exception', 'has_app_context', 'has_request_context', 'helpers', 'json', 'json_available', 'jsonify', 'make_response', 'message_flashed', 'redirect', 'render_template', 'render_template_string', 'request', 'request_finished', 'request_started', 'request_tearing_down', 'safe_join', 'send_file', 'send_from_directory', 'session', 'sessions', 'signals', 'signals_available', 'stream_with_context', 'template_rendered', 'templating', 'url_for', 'wrappers']
```

Hm ... looks not so promising but someone or some place of changes documentation shoud show, when this import broke in flask-uploads.

Comment: when I use flask.ext.uploads the error says it's deprecated and use flask_uploads instead. But even that doesn't work

Comment: Im kinda new in this, how do I check this sys,path? and what do you mean if the module is in one of the visited places?

Comment: This list does show up but what happens next? I still cant import it

Comment: I guess I can wait

Answer (score 0):

Update 2020:

You should import `from flask_uploads import Uploadset`.

The PyPi package of `Flask-Uploads` is broken since February 2020.

You can use the drop-in replacement `Flask-Reuploaded`.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/